# Running a report from Oracle application

Tags: oracle, oraclereports, oracle-apps

Running the report from view->requests  in oracle apps , no data retrieved but the same SQL retrieve data from PLSQL developer and Report builder .

Comment: You need to provide additional information in order for anyone to be able to help you. Are you connecting with the same schema in each instance? Is it possible that the schema the Oracle application is using doesn't have the required privilege(s) to see the data? Were you ever able to query data from within the Oracle application, and if so, what has changed since then? These are some ideas to get you thinking. I would suggest editing your question to include more information so that someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following

- Schema name and privilege on the Data source being used in the Report VS the apps user

Alternatively you can check in the SQL session by initializing it with

```
fnd_global.APPS_INITIALIZE(user_id=>l_user_id, 
                           resp_id=>l_resp_id, 
                           resp_appl_id=>l_resp_appl_id);    

l_user_id is the fnd user ID which will be utilized during the call. 
l_resp_id is the responsibility ID 
l_resp_appl_id is the responsibility application ID
```